# Global & Local variables in Javascript

Tags: javascript, global, local

I have one variable and two functions . The variable is used by both. and the first function is changing the variable value (globally) each time it's used by it . This is what I want but it is not working with me .

```
x = 1;

function f1()
{
  x = x + 1;
  // use x 
} 

function f2()
{
  // use x
}
```

I've read other threads but x is always 1 which is very frustrating :|

added: actual code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function S4() {
return (((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000) | 0).toString(16).substring(1);
}

function guid() {
return (S4() + S4() + ";" + S4() + ";" + S4() + ";" + S4() + ";" + S4() + S4() + S4());
}

P = '';

function Save() {
P = guid();
$('#btnBrowse').uploadifyUpload();
}

$(document).ready(function () {


            $('#txtText').elastic();

            $('#btnBrowse').uploadify({
                'uploader': '../uploadify.swf',
                'script': '../uploadify.ashx',
                'cancelImg': '/uploadify/cancel.png',
                'folder': '../images/Albums/',
                'multi': true,
                'fileDesc': 'Web Image Files (.JPG, .GIF, .PNG)',
                'fileExt': '*.jpg;*.gif;*.png',
                'scriptData': { 'Album_ID': P },
                'buttonText': 'Upload Images'
            });

});

</script>
```

so the variable is P . and it is used by jquery function (uploadify) . each time I excute
Save function I expect I get a new value for variable P . But is always the same ??

Comment: Please show us your _actual_ code.

Comment: The code you posted should work. Show a usage example that doesn't work (and how it doesn't work).

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you posted

Comment: @HTB I think you intended for `()` after `f1` and `f2` otherwise the function fails to execute.

Comment: the problem is the code is really long. any way, the second function is jquery function . does this change the  case ?

Comment: "is not working for me" is not a very good explanation of what's not working, error messages, actual behavior, intended behaviors are better ways to get others to answer the question

Comment: @Juan Mendes what I expect is to increase x by 1 but it is always 1 .

Comment: @HTB: Your updated code demonstrates no issue, and as such is not useful. You should take the time to provide code that is a verified reproduction of the issue you're having, or simply provide the actual problematic code.

Comment: @patrick dw: I posted the actual code .

Comment: @HTB: *"...each time I excute Save function I expect I get a new value for variable P."* But where are you calling `Save()`? Your code doesn't show it ever being invoked.

Comment: The problem is the time *when* you execute the code. The `uplodify` options are set on *page load* (which includes that *P* is passed on page load) but the the value *P* is only set *after* the function *save* was called (which is some time later I guess).

Comment: @patrick dw: man it is invoked from html button click event :)

Comment: @Felix Kling: ok good . What do you suggest please to solve the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is *the time* when you execute the code. The uplodify options are set on *page load* (which includes that `P` is passed on page load) and as `P` is a string, changing `P` later (through `save()`) will not change the value you passed.

<del>You can solve this by passing a reference to the object as option, instead of the string</del>  *Edit: Didn't work.*

The plugin provides a [`uploadifySettings` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/methods/uploadifysettings/) method to change the settings of an uploadify instance. Use it to update the `scriptData` settings:

```
function Save() {
    $('#btnBrowse').uploadifySettings('scriptData', {'Album_ID' : guid()}, true);
    $('#btnBrowse').uploadifyUpload();
}
```

Comment: Felix, I tried to upload an image after modifying the code but error showed that Album_ID is empty .

Comment: yeeeeeeees :) . Finally it worked . I was in a really bad mood . Thank you very much Felix . I really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this fiddle can help you understand global scope a little better: http://jsfiddle.net/XFx27/1/

```
var x = 0;

function add1()
{
 x = x + 1;
}

function show()
{
    alert(x);
}

add1();
show(); //alerts 1
add1();
show(); //alerts 2
```

Your missing parens () after your functions function funcName()

Answer (score 0):

```
x = 1;

function f1()
{
  x = x + 1;
  // use x 
} 

function f2()
{
  // use x
}

// x is 1

f1();

// x is 2

f2();
```

Answer (score 0):

firstly, the f1 function should be:

```
function f1(){
   x = x + 1;
   // use x
}
```

---

```
var x;

function f1(){
    x = x + 1;
    console.log(x);
}

function f2(){
    console.log(x);
}

f1(); // 2
f2(); // 2
```

I tried the code in chrome console and I think it really works.

Comment: the second function is jquery function

Comment: you can try to set x's value in a prop, and read it in jQuery.